# Do I need to format or prep my external SSD in order to run Ubuntu as a 2nd OS?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, hard-drive, ssd

Please help, I have a removable 1Tb SSD. I would like to use it to run Debian distributions from time to time while keeping my main OS (Windows 10) on my internal HDD intact. Is it possible and if so, how would I go about setting it up?

I hope to use the SSD to run Ubuntu 16.04LTS so that I can learn Linux and command line. In addition, I would like to leave some room on the 1tb external SSD for an additional Debian distribution. That way I can better experience the flavors of Linux without confusing myself. I am really relying on the help of more seasoned users and thankfully this site is conducive.

p.s., and in full disclosure, I am very new to Linux based operating systems and this forum. Also, I have very little schema/background knowledge regarding removable hard drives and SSD's. Any advice or guidance will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your time and support.

Comment: My problem is purely a lack of knowledge about using removable hard drives. Will it need to be formatted before putting the OS on the SSD, etc? If you know of a link or anything that would help... I've never done this before. Thanks.

Comment: Just exactly the same as when you installed it on the internal drive, same format (ext4) and what ever partitions you want. Make a live usb, boot it and choose `something else` in the installer to set the drive up. There is no difference to installing on an internal or external drive. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu for detailed install instructions.

Comment: Good practice is to remove all other drives first, so you don't format the wrong one by mistake.

Comment: Thank you. I will go to work on that now. If you can set your comment thread to answers, I'd like to mark it as accepted/helpful.

Comment: Try to install it first, if you get any issues you can then update this question. It is always a good idea to test thing before accepting answers ;)

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.

Comment: waltinator, thank you for the homework. Between you and @Mark Kirby I feel I have a lot better understanding. Possibly avoided Traumatic Brain Injury from head vs wall.